# Как работают stage и Scene в telegraf.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите пожалуйста.  Что я хочу сделать, следующий сценарий.

1. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку “/start”. 
   Активируется сцена - welcomeScene
2. Пользователь выбирает одну из ролей отображаемых в кастомной клавиатуре ( пассажир/водитель) В зависимости от выбранной роли, происходит инициализация сцены ( либо passengerScene, либо либо driverScene)
3. После “обработки” выбранной сцены, пользователь возвращается обратно на главную сцену т.е. WelcomeScene  В сценах passagerScene и driverScene будет происходит сбор информации для составления маршрута.   Как будут этим пользоваться люди? Если пользователю необходимо доехать от точки А до точки Б, то он пишет об этом боту, бот в свою очередь переправит сообщение в общую группу для водителей.   Помогите пожалуйста, направьте меня пусть истинный.  Я понимаю, что не совсем понимаю как работать со сцена и со стейджем в telegraf.js

driverScene.js

```js
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard');
const Scene = require('telegraf/scenes/base');
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup');
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage');
const {enter , leave} = Stage;

const driverScene = new  WizardScene (
    'driver',
    (ctx) => {
        let keyboard_buttons = Markup.keyboard(['Я водитель']).oneTime().resize().extra();
        ctx.reply('Кто вы?', keyboard_buttons);
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    (ctx) => {
        ctx.wizard.state.role = ctx.message.text;
        ctx.reply(`Я ${ctx.wizard.state.role}`);
        return leave();
        
    });
module.exports = driverScene ;
```

passagerScene.js

```js
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard');
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup');
const {enter} = require('telegraf/stage');

const passagerScene = new  WizardScene (
    'passager',
    (ctx) => {
        let keyboard_buttons = Markup.keyboard(['Я пассажир']).oneTime().resize().extra();
        ctx.reply('Кто вы ?', keyboard_buttons);
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    (ctx) => {
        ctx.wizard.state.role = ctx.message.text;
        ctx.reply(`Вы ${ctx.wizard.state.role}`);
        return ctx.scene.leave();
        
    });
module.exports = passagerScene ;
```

welcomeScene.js

```js
const WizardScene = require('telegraf/scenes/wizard');
const Markup = require('telegraf/markup');
const {leave} = require('telegraf/stage');

const welcomeSetting = new  WizardScene (
    'welcome',
    (ctx) => {
        let keyboard_buttons = Markup.keyboard(['Водитель'],['Пассажир']).oneTime().resize().extra();
        ctx.reply('welcome!', keyboard_buttons);
        return ctx.wizard.next();
    },
    (ctx) => {
        ctx.reply(`leave main scene`);
        return leave();
        
    });
module.exports = welcomeSetting ;
```

index.js

```js
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const session = require('telegraf/session');
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage');
const { enter , leave} = Stage;

const passagerScene = require('./controllers/passager');
const driverScene = require('./controllers/driver');
const welcomeScene = require('./controllers/welcome');

const stage = new Stage([passagerScene,driverScene,welcomeScene]);


const bot = new Telegraf('TOKEN');

bot.use(Telegraf.log());
bot.use(session());
bot.use(stage.middleware());
bot.hears('order',(ctx) => enter('order'));
bot.hears('setting',(ctx) => enter('setting'));

bot.launch()
```

Помогите пожалуйста. 
Уже неделю не могу найти ответ. 
В официальной документации, некоторые примеры не рабочие.

Comment: Вот на эту тему [хороший видос](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFX8A2MhLes&list=PLvZr_OuGmjB2TBuCDXZna8ANOQovonPQU&index=2).